# How to Extract DDLs from Microsoft Parallel Data Warehouse?

Tags: parallel-data-warehouse

Please suggest How to Generate the scripts from Microsoft Parallel Data Warehouse...

I have already tried using SSMS 2016 by using my PDW credentials... 
But i failed to Generate the scripts...

Regards,

Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to go to SSMS 2016 and go to the Tools menu and choose Check for Updates. Install the [latest update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-sql-server-management-studio-july-2016-release/) out in the last month or so supports Azure SQL DW which is a similar MPP surface area. It may support PDW but I'm not sure.

If that doesn't work, go the tried and true route. Search the Microsoft download center for [Analytics Platform System Appliance Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=Analytics%20Platform%20System%20Appliance%20Update%20&form=dlc) and then choose the version that matches your PDW. Download the .chm help file. Then you have to right click on the .chm file and choose Properties then unblock it in order to open it.

Then search for "Install SQL Server database tooling for Visual Studio" and it documents how to install SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio and connect SQL Server Object Explorer. Then you can expand and view a list of tables/sprocs/etc and script them out by right clicking on a table or sproc in SQL Server Object Explorer.

Comment: Greg, 
Thanks for the details...

SSMS 2016 Its already up-to date, I can able to Expand view a list of tables/sprocs etc... 
The Problem is I am not able to generate  the DDL Scripts   from PDW... I tried with Powershell as well, But to FAIL :(